# Anonymous Subclass of array? I think? Don't understand this syntax

Tags: java, anonymous-class

I'm not a Java programmer but have to do some Java work. From some googling, this seems like an anonymous subclass. But then the Object is followed by "[]". But then again the variable is declared is an Object. Is this just contravariance with the most generic type (Object) allowing an Array of Objects?

```
Object thing = new Object[] {someInt, anotherInt, someInterface, someString};
```

Comment: as a sidenode, using an `Object[]` to store different types isn´t the best idea to smoothly work with.

Comment: Yup, not my code. Reading somebody else. Though I guess in this case it's a onetime thing to pass these for values but still a bit hacky.

Comment: @lanza I'd consider that a warning sign. As Kevin said, using an `Object[]` isn't very smooth (it's clearly a class of some sort), and the assignment to `Object` just adds to the What The Fudge factor.

Answer (score 6):

No. Arrays are final so you can't subclass them. The code just creates an object array `Object[]` and at creation time fills it with some ints (autoboxed to `Integer`), an interface and a String.

The "odd" thing about the example is that it assigns the `Object[]` to an `Object` reference. Now all classes extend `Object` including arrays, so this is valid, but I can't imagine any case where it would make sense to have `Object thing` instead of `Object[] thing` unless you're intentionally trying to make your code less clear.

Comment: Great, thanks. The `Object thing` instead of `Object[] thing` had me confused.

Comment: @lanza I wrote [an answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37696382/3788176) earlier this week which I think may help to remove some of your confusion about `Object` vs `Object[]`.

Comment: @AndyTurner Nice answer.

Comment: @Kayaman thanks. And to be clear, I wasn't adding it here for self-promotion :) it felt genuinely relevant.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yeah I didn't think so. It's relevant, informative and succinct.